# Joining "translate" and "substring" expressions together

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two expressions which I would like to be joined into one.

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(content,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(content,1,4)"/>
```

The first one extracts all numbers from **content** in the xml, while the other one removes all but the 4 first characters.

```
<!-- The wanted result is "1234" but using only the first expression I get "1234547" -->
<content> numbers 1234 more numbers 547 </content>
```

I first want to extract the numbers, *then* keep the first 4 characters from that result, and thus these two needs to be joined somehow.

I've tried something like this but could not manage to make it work.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(content,1,4,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
```

EDIT: I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: *"The first one extracts all numbers from **content**"* I don't think it does, because the outer expression refers to `content` while the inner one refers to the context node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(content, translate(content, '0123456789', ''), ''), 1, 4)"/>
```

This is assuming that "remove" here:

> I first want to extract the numbers, *then* remove the first 4 characters from that result

actually means "keep" or "extract".

Comment: That worked wonders! And yea that was a mistake on my part, I've fixed it now.